# RuntimeException causes ANR on Android

Tags: android, crashlytics, android-anr-dialog

I have a problem with my Android application. When I throw RuntimeException it causes ANR instead of crash.

For example, I have such code:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    throw RuntimeException("Test crash")
}
```

And when I click on this button aplication freezes for some time and then shows alert about ANR.

I have read similar question, otlined here: [RuntimeException causes ANR instead of crash in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180423/runtimeexception-causes-anr-instead-of-crash-in-android)

But I can't figure out how to fix it. I checked everything I could: no UncaughtExceptionHandler-s attached, I do not use outdated google-play-services library. Where should I look for the cause of the problem?

Interesting thing that I can see stacktrace in logcat after I click this button:

```
2021-08-04 09:05:39.464 8764-8764/wa.testapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: wa.testapp, PID: 8764
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Test crash
        at com.example.testapp.ui.main.FragmentMain.onViewCreated$lambda-7(FragmentMain.kt:102)
        at com.example.testapp.ui.main.FragmentMain.$r8$lambda$agRVJ2mByrrRLVPpioFH6VVBf9s(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.testapp.ui.main.FragmentMain$$ExternalSyntheticLambda8.onClick(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2021-08-04 09:05:39.467 8764-8764/wa.testapp E/a: Exception:
    message: Test crash
    localized message: Test crash
    stack trace:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Test crash
        at com.example.testapp.ui.main.FragmentMain.onViewCreated$lambda-7(FragmentMain.kt:102)
        at com.example.testapp.ui.main.FragmentMain.$r8$lambda$agRVJ2mByrrRLVPpioFH6VVBf9s(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.testapp.ui.main.FragmentMain$$ExternalSyntheticLambda8.onClick(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reason of such behaviour. The reason is a `com.smartlook.recording:app:1.1.2-native` dependency. After removing this library from project everything works fine.